# rvest package to harvest instagram number of followers?

Tags: r, instagram, rvest

I'm trying to adapt the example code in the `rvest` package for getting number of followers for an account on instagram (e.g., `https://www.instagram.com/bradyellison/`). I tried using `selectorgadget` to isolate code for number of followers, which gave me this: `._218yx:nth-child(2) ._s53mj`. But I don't get the expected followers back, and not sure how to debug this. Here's my code.

```
# example 
require(rvest)
html <- read_html("https://www.instagram.com/bradyellison/")
athlete_followers <- html_nodes(html, "._218yx:nth-child(2) ._s53mj")
length(athlete_followers)
```

Output is:

```
[1] 0
```

Expected followers are 12.1K. Would really appreciate help. (I've tried using the Instagram API for this first, but couldn't get it to work, perhaps because I'm in sandbox mode or something.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `rvest` this page because it's not a static site, rather it's generated dynamically via code (e.g. try `xml_text(html)`). To access Instagram data you should use their API. See full example here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/analyze-instagram-with-r/ .

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried following the full API example you gave, but I think I'm setting up something wrong on the Instagram site because I get the following error:  `> test <- getUser("barackobama", mytoken)
Error in getUser("barackobama", mytoken) : 
  Error. User name not found. Does this application have permission to access public content?`